# Does async pipe trigger onPush change detection in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe, angular2-changedetection

I've checked multiple places for above question but found conflicting answers. For example in [angular university](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/#:%7E:text=if%20an%20observable%20linked%20to%20the%20template%20via%20the%20async%20pipe%20emits%20a%20new%20value) it says that change detection gets triggered when async pipe gets a new observable value. But I found on multiple medium articles that say that it marks for check only. Async pipe [code reference](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/dd177e2c1809b39b57adef53e3f29409acae7290/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L148) also seems to support that.

Can someone tell what does actually happen in this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The a zonefull application, the AsyncPipe will only mark a component as dirty (via calling `markForCheck`).

`markForCheck` doesn't not trigger a change detection per se but OnPush component are only change detected when they are dirty.

What often happens is that the AsyncPipe is triggered somehow/somewhere by a Promise resolving (a HTTP call) or a user action. Both of those do trigger a change detection.

So in a sense yes the AsyncPipe will trigger a change detection, but not directly.